# Windows doesn't show up as bootable operating system on Mac

Tags: windows-7, macos, boot, multi-boot

My MacBook Air running Windows 7 got messed up after my cat forced power off. After a reboot, I kept getting a STOP error trying to boot, and my OS X installation vanished as a bootable OS (and the partition was corrupted -- missing Volume Name, attempts to repair failed with something about invalid B-Tree) when using the option key at startup.

I've since reinstalled OS X using the web download recovery thing, but now my Windows partition doesn't show as a bootable option when using option key at startup, although it does show up in the Startup Disk preference.

When I try to boot Windows by using the Startup Disk preference, I just get a flashing cursor in the top-left.

How can I get OS X to properly recognise the Windows partition (i.e. that it shows up in the list of bootable partitions when holding down the option key at startup)? Hopefully the OS X installation didn't touch the Windows partition, so I should at least be able to boot into WinRE... currently can't even do that.